# Error when filtering DataFrame with a call to loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am a complete Python and Pandas novice. I am following a tutorial, and so far have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly as pyplot
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("GlobalLandTemperaturesByCountry.csv")
df = df.drop("AverageTemperatureUncertainty", axis=1)
df = df.rename(columns={"dt": "Date"})
df = df.rename(columns={"AverageTemperature": "AvTemp"})
df = df.dropna()

df_countries = df.groupby(["Country", "Date"]).sum().reset_index().sort_values("Date", ascending=False)

start_date = "2001-01-01"
end_date = "2002-01-01"
mask = (df_countries["Date"] > start_date) & (df_countries["Date"] <= end_date)

df_mask = df_countries.loc(mask)
```

When I try and run the code, I get an error on the last line, i.e. `df_mask = df_countries.loc(mask)`, the error being:

```
TypeError 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I have already found several StackOverflow answers for this error, but none seem to match my scenario enough to help. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: how about `df_countries.loc[mask]` or `df_countries[mask]` , [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Answer (score 0):

In above example df_countries is dataframe and mask seems to be condition which is to be applied on this dataframe.

The object is mutable, meaning that its value can be changed without reassigning it the same variable, its contents will change at some point in the code. As a result, its hash value will change, so they cannot be hashed.

Try:

df_mask = df_countries.loc[(mask)]